# Python - Diagonal Match in a 2-Dimensional Array

Tags: python, arrays

I need help with diagonal matching in a 2D Array in Python when 3 or more elements are the same.

In the scenario below, the "2"'s formulate a diagonal match. Thus, I want to make them "-2" since they form a match.

**Given**

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [3, 1, 2, 0, 0],  # 2 at index 2
 [1, 2, 1, 0, 0],  # 2 at index 1
 [2, 3, 3, 0, 0]]  # 2 at index 0
```

**Result**

```
[[0,  0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0,  0, 0, 0, 0],
 [3,  1,-2, 0, 0],  # -2 now at index 2
 [1, -2, 1, 0, 0],  # -2 now at index 1
 [-2, 3, 3, 0, 0]]  # -2 now at index 0
```

I presume they are multiple directions for a diagonal match (from the left/right) so I want to cover those cases. Ideally, I want to do this without importing any module.

Thanks (:

Comment: Have you got any code you can include in your question? Or are you asking  the community to provide code from scratch? Or, well what's your question?

Comment: Can't you just do brute force and check all diagonals?

Comment: I am unsure how to approach this. If someone can point me to the right direction on approaching this with a while loop? Thanks

Comment: I could manually check all diagonals but the 2D array won’t always be the same size

Comment: @MTG You could get the size dynamically, no?

Comment: @jhpratt, I can get the number of rows and columns? So I am presuming I will have two methods of checking? One from the left and the other from the right? But I am unsure how I will format my while loop to check in this manner. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to start from, assuming length of the rows is the same and you want full length diagonals:

```
#get diagonals, number of diagonals is 2 * additional rows, where
#multiplication by 2 is for left and right diagonal
diagonals = [[] for asymmetry in range((len(test)%len(test[0])+1)*2)]
for i, diagonal in enumerate(diagonals):
    for rowidx in range(len(test[0])):
        #if left diagonal
        if i % 2 == 0:
            diagonal.append(test[i//2+rowidx][rowidx])
        #if right diagonal
        elif i % 2 == 1:
            diagonal.append(test[i//2+rowidx][len(test[0])-rowidx-1])
#Now check for same values in diagonals
for i, diagonal in enumerate(diagonals):
    for value in set(diagonal):
        #indeces of repeating values:
        valueidx = [j for j, val in enumerate(diagonal) if val==value]
        #if value repeats and is not 0 and that they're ordered:
        if len(valueidx) > 2 and value is not 0 and all(a-1 == b for a, b in zip(valueidx[1:], valueidx[:-1])):
            for idx in valueidx:
                #case of left diagonal
                if i % 2 == 0:
                    test[i//2 + idx][idx] *=-1
                #case of right diagonal
                if i % 2 == 1:
                    test[i//2 + idx][len(test[0])-idx-1] *=-1
```

It should be possible to simplify this code by a lot, but here is something to start from. Using numpy would simplify the code by a lot, using `numpy.diag` and simple expressions for replacing the values.

```
test = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [3, 1, 2, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
        [2, 3, 3, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 3, 0, 1]]
```

after running above script:

```
test
[[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [ 3,-1,-2, 0, 0],
 [ 1,-2,-1, 0, 0],
 [-2, 3, 3, 0, 0],
 [ 0, 1, 3, 0,-1]]
```

Comment: Why does it negate the `1`s? The diagonal is broken.

Comment: I assumed the task was to make numbers negative if they're repeated based on the question. As you see, 1 is repeated 3 times in the second left diagonal.

The last line of code manipulates the value. If the value is repeated I was simply multiplying it by -1. By editing the last line of the code, you can set the new value to whatever you want it to be.

Comment: No, I agree with that. It's just, I assumed the OP wanted unbroken diagonals. `test[4][3]` is `0`, not `-1`.

Comment: OP first sentence "when 3 or more elements are the same" does not refer to order. However, if ordered sequence is required, it is just a simple edit of checking whether `idx` in `valueidx` all have difference of 1.

Comment: Thanks @zck but I should have clarified. As "OldBunny2800" mentioned. The diagonals have to be unbroken. Is there anything we can tweak in the code so it reflects this? Also, the number of rows/columns won't always be the same but I can obtain those values by using the len() as long as it doesn't throw off the algorithm to find diagonals. Do you think it will? Thanks

Comment: This is trivial, just add `and all(a-1 == b for a, b in zip(valueidx[1:], valueidx[:-1]))` to the line that checks length of `valueidx`. Can you accept the answer? This should be definetely something to go on. Luckily it's in a simple form too, upper loop get diagonals, second loop checks for contents and adjusts the input list of lists. I'll edit the answer to account for 'unbroken' diagonal.